# How to unique the email?

Tags: javascript, html, function, html-email, indexof

```
<body>
    <p>Enter your email:</p>
        <input id="email" style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 2px;" type="email" 
        placeholder="Email: ">
        <input onclick= "formSubmission(email)" type="submit" 
        value="Submit">

    <script>

          const formRecord = []
          const formSubmission = (email) =>{
                if (email.value){
                       if (email.value.indexOf('@')){
                             formRecord.push(`Email :` + email.value)
                       }
                       else{
                             alert(`Please enter the valid email!`)
                       }
                }
                else{
                       return alert(`Please fill the area of email!`)
                }
                document.write(formRecord)
          }

    </script>
</body>
```

I wrote this logic to unique the email by '@' but the output is not comming well.
Please tell me how i can encapsulate the email without Regular Expression.

Comment: And why do you absolutely want to avoid regular expressions's super powers?

Comment: Checking for just the existence of the `@` symbol isn't enough to validate an email address.

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work, you just have to adjust the line `if (email.value.indexOf('@')) {` to `if (email.value.indexOf('@') > -1) {`

But for stuff like this, RegExp really is your best choice...

```js
const formRecord = []
const formSubmission = (email) => {
  if (email.value) {
    if (email.value.indexOf('@') > -1) {
      formRecord.push(`Email :` + email.value)
    } else {
      alert(`Please enter the valid email!`)
    }
  } else {
    return alert(`Please fill the area of email!`)
  }
  document.write(formRecord)
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Enter your email:</p>
  <input id="email" style="margin-bottom: 20px; margin-top: 2px;" type="email" placeholder="Email: ">
  <input onclick="formSubmission(email)" type="submit" value="Submit">

</body>
```

Comment: Good answer! Thank you!

Comment: @MianDanial you're welcome... please consider marking it as the accepted answer, if it helped you :)